# How to sort json array elements in java

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I know that there is a method to sort maps in json

with

```
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);
```

by `fasterxml`

But when i got such an array:

```
{
  "testArray": [
    {
      "firstName": {
        "value": "Lui"
      },
      "lastName": {
        "value": "Armstrong"
      },
      "photo": "234"
    }, {
      "firstName": {
        "value": "Charley"
      },
      "lastName": {
        "value": "Mor"
      },
      "photo": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

I guess to sort it by first equals field value, if field keys are equals. So i need the  first element in example was after the last, cause word `Charley` must be before `Lui`, and they both got the same path - `firstName.value`. The order of keys is the same, cause of `ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS`. So if path is the same, i expect the order of elements must base on the values, but it does not happens.

I try to use

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setNodeFactory(new JsonNodeFactory() {
    @Override
    public ObjectNode objectNode() {
        return new ObjectNode(this, new TreeMap<String, JsonNode>());
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayNode arrayNode() {
        return new ArrayNode(this, new SomeSortedArrayListThatBaseOnComparatorInComstructor<JsonNode>(new Comparator<JsonNode>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final JsonNode o1, final JsonNode o2) {
                return //logic to compare
            }
        }) { });
```

But when i call

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject)
```

the code dont use my `JsonNodeFactory`. In debug there is not thread appear in methods `objectNode()` or `arrayNode()`.

I cant understand why.

Or maybe there is another method to sort such a jsons?

Add some search results for better google searching:
`How to sort array of json objects in java`,
`How can I sort a JSONArray of objects in JAVA`,
`How to sort json objects using the order of another json`
`sort json array elements java`

Comment: Would it be an option to transfer the json content into plain java objects for sorting them? Sometimes does a direct way not exists?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/326807/reporter I guess i can move it to an object, but if i got a json with a lot of nestings, it seems to be dirty to sort all inner json arrays converting them to objects and define comparator for each of them.  Still, i cant understand why there is no usage of JsonNodeFactory in code... If only thread appear in factory i  guess it solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution

i need to call `readTree`, that use `JsonNodeFactory`

and then convert to string by `writeValueAsString`

Here a code

```
public static String writeAsSortedJson(Object object) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setNodeFactory(getArrayNodeKeyValueSortingNodeFactory());

    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);

    String preparedJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(preparedJson);

    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
}

@SuppressWarnings("JavaNCSS")
public static JsonNodeFactory getArrayNodeKeyValueSortingNodeFactory() {
    return new JsonNodeFactory() {
        @Override
        public ObjectNode objectNode() {
            return new ObjectNode(this, new TreeMap<String, JsonNode>());
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("JavaNCSS")
        @Override
        public ArrayNode arrayNode() {
            return new ArrayNode(this, new SortedArrayList<JsonNode>(new Comparator<JsonNode>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(final JsonNode o1, final JsonNode o2) {
                    return compareRecursively(o1, o2);
                }

                private int compareRecursively(final JsonNode o1, final JsonNode o2) {
                    if (o1.isObject() && o2.isObject()) {
                        return compareObjectNodes(o1, o2);
                    } else if (o1.isObject()) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (o2.isObject()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (o1.isArray() && o2.isArray()) {
                        return compareArrayNodes(o1, o2);
                    } else if (o1.isArray()) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (o2.isArray()) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    return o1.asText().compareTo(o2.asText());
                }

                private int compareArrayNodes(final JsonNode o1, final JsonNode o2) {
                    List<JsonNode> elements1 = Lists.newArrayList(o1.elements());
                    List<JsonNode> elements2 = Lists.newArrayList(o2.elements());

                    for (int i = 0; i < elements1.size() || i < elements2.size(); i++) {
                        if (i >= elements1.size()) {
                            return -1;
                        } else if (i >= elements2.size()) {
                            return 1;
                        }

                        JsonNode jsonNode1 = elements1.get(i);
                        JsonNode jsonNode2 = elements2.get(i);
                        int compareRecursively = compareRecursively(jsonNode1, jsonNode2);
                        if (compareRecursively != 0) {
                            return compareRecursively;
                        }
                    }

                    return 0;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("ReturnCountExtended")
                private int compareObjectNodes(JsonNode o1, JsonNode o2) {
                    List<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> elements1 = Lists.newArrayList(o1.fields());
                    List<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> elements2 = Lists.newArrayList(o2.fields());
                    if (elements1.isEmpty() && elements2.isEmpty()) {
                        return 0;
                    } else if (elements1.isEmpty()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (elements2.isEmpty()) {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < elements1.size() || i < elements2.size(); i++) {
                        if (i >= elements1.size()) {
                            return -1;
                        } else if (i >= elements2.size()) {
                            return 1;
                        }

                        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry1 = elements1.get(i);
                        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry2 = elements2.get(i);
                        int compare = entry1.getKey().compareTo(entry2.getKey());
                        if (compare == 0) {
                            int compareRecursively = compareRecursively(entry1.getValue(), entry2.getValue());
                            if (compareRecursively != 0) {
                                return compareRecursively;
                            }
                        } else {
                            return compare;
                        }
                    }

                    return 0;
                }
            }) { });
        }
    };
}

public static class SortedArrayList<T> implements List<T> {
    private final List<T> delegate = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Comparator<T> comparator;

    public SortedArrayList(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return delegate.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return delegate.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(final Object o) {
        return delegate.contains(o);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return delegate.iterator();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return delegate.toArray();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public <T1> T1[] toArray(@NotNull final T1[] a) {
        return delegate.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final T t) {
        boolean add = delegate.add(t);
        sort();
        return add;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(final int index, final T element) {
        delegate.add(index, element);
        sort();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(final Object o) {
        boolean remove = delegate.remove(o);
        sort();
        return remove;
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(final int index) {
        T remove = delegate.remove(index);
        sort();
        return remove;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(@NotNull final Collection<?> c) {
        return delegate.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(@NotNull final Collection<? extends T> c) {
        boolean addAll = delegate.addAll(c);
        sort();
        return addAll;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, @NotNull Collection<? extends T> c) {
        boolean addAll = delegate.addAll(index, c);
        sort();
        return addAll;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(@NotNull final Collection<?> c) {
        boolean removeAll = delegate.removeAll(c);
        sort();
        return removeAll;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(@NotNull final Collection<?> c) {
        boolean retainAll = delegate.retainAll(c);
        sort();
        return retainAll;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        delegate.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        SortedArrayList<?> that = (SortedArrayList<?>) o;
        return Objects.equals(delegate, that.delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public T get(final int index) {
        return delegate.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public T set(final int index, final T element) {
        delegate.set(index, element);
        sort();
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(final Object o) {
        return delegate.indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(final Object o) {
        return delegate.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        return delegate.listIterator();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(final int index) {
        return delegate.listIterator(index);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<T> subList(final int fromIndex, final int toIndex) {
        return delegate.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    private void sort() {
        delegate.sort(comparator);
    }
}
```

Comment: If objects is not an `isObject` or  `isArray`, than it is `isPojo`,  `isNumber`  `isIntegralNumber` `isFloatingPointNumber` `isShort` `isInt` `isLong` `isFloat` `isDouble` `isBigDecimal` `isBigInteger` `isTextual` `isBoolean` `isNull` `isBinary`, than we can compare them all by `asText` method. All of them, except of `isPojo`. I actually dont know how to compare such a nodes rigth. If you know, write here you solution and i will update code.

Comment: "configurable"? By what? By specify comparator for each type of elements? That is not an answer. Your code will not work for unknown-structured elemens, but will work for known-structured elements. I didnt ignore your answer. I ask you a question.

Comment: A normal person in such a situation, if he knows that he is right, proves his case, step by step, especially responsible for his every word. If you delete your words, then you are simply not able to answer for them. A responsible person is responsible for every word, including erroneous ones, only in the case of erroneous words he admits that it is a mistake. You just delete your words, so you are not able to answer for them. I don't know how old you are, but either answer for what you write, or goodbye.

Comment: As the smoke disappears , so will they disappear